# Run tkinter gui on remote machine connected by SSH?

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch, tkinter

I would like to run a tkinter-generated GUI generated on a Raspberry Pi while connected via SSH on a Mac.  I have tried several suggestions (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37604289/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable) but none seem to work.  All of the variations including modifications to /etc/sudoers and ~./bashrc have failed with consistent messages "_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable" or something similar on the remote machine.  The tkinter GUI works fine on the host Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Stretch.  All I want to do is project the GUI onto the remote client.  I'd appreciate any help including referrals to previous discussions that I might have missed.

Comment: Were U able to make this work? I often need to do this working with and SSH linux other than just pi, while my local machine is windows.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is an X Window System application and needs an X Display to show itself on. In X Windows you can specify a local or remote display using the DISPLAY environment variable or `-display` parameter. How you do this depends on your system but if you want to display on the local display it needs to be running a desktop session and you need permission (typically via xauth) to connect to that display. The local display will most likely be `DISPLAY=:0.0` and you can configure this for your Tkinter application. Permission is usually handled via tokens stored in `$HOME/.Xauthority` so if you are using ssh as the same user that is logged into the desktop then just setting DISPLAY will be sufficient. If not you can copy the token from the logged in user to your ssh user using:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
sudo xauth -f ~xuser/.Xauthority extract - $DISPLAY | xauth merge -
```

If you want the Tkinter application to appear on your *local* display then you can tunnel the X protocol using `ssh -X user@remotehost` which will setup a tunnel and configure the DISPLAY environment variable on the server so that X Window applications will draw on your local desktop. Works if you are using X Windows locally (ie: linux desktop or Windows with an X Windows implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - you can’t.

The Mac doesn’t have an X client, although there are options to install one (which is off-topic).

Viable options are to use RealVNC to display a virtual screen on the Mac or run a tkinter program on the Mac remotely accessing the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

MacOs no longer provides an X11 server by default (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341 for details), and X11 is used by tkinter to display its windows. However, a work-around for this is to download X11 directly (this can be found here: https://www.xquartz.org/, and as explained in the support.apple link is still supported by apple).

Then, with this installed, you should be able to just ssh to your Pi using `ssh -X pi@ipaddress` where -X just means to "forward your display", and then just run whatever your tkinter script is, and the window should pop up on your mac!

(If you run into troubles, here's a relevant StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453188/matplotlib-display-plot-on-a-remote-machine)

Cheers!